# ActiveRecord models of same class not comparable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am quite puzzled with following phenomenon in Ruby+Rails: Sometimes I do ActiveRecord object comparisons. This usually works, but sometimes when I run a test suite they fail, eventhough the records are the same:

```
[26] pry(#<Object>)> auth_user == user
=> false
[27] pry(#<Object>)> user.id == user.id 
=> true
[29] pry(#<Object>)> auth_user.class == user.class
=> false
```

OK not the same class, but:

```
[30] pry(#<Object>)> auth_user.class.name == user.class.name
=> true
[31] pry(#<Object>)> user.class.name
=> "User"
[32] pry(#<Object>)> auth_user.class.name
=> "User"
```

... also interesting:

```
[33] pry(#<Object>)> auth_user.class.object_id
=> 54456360
[34] pry(#<Object>)> user.class.object_id
=> 58110660
```

I understand that the comparison fails, because the class objects are different. But how is it even possible to have two classes by the same name?

Another simpler example: I have `author` an instance of `User`:

```
[39] pry(#<Object>)> author
=> #<User:0x00000000079d8300
 id: 23,
 login: "noemie.schowalter",
 email: nil,
 password_digest: [FILTERED],
 given_name: "Noemie">
```

Now I fetch another instance of the same record:

```
[40] pry(#<Object>)> author2 = User.find(author.id)
=> #<User:0x0000000008428648
 id: 23,
 login: "noemie.schowalter",
 email: nil,
 password_digest: [FILTERED],
 given_name: "Noemie">
```

The weird thing is:

```
[41] pry(#<Object>)> author == author2 
=> false
```

It appears when I run test suites in parallel (`parallelize workers: 4`) in Ruby 2.5.5 and Rails 6.0.0.

Comment: What is `auth_user.class` and `user.class`??

Comment: I mean, I can write a trivial bit of code that replicates this behaviour, but I doubt it will be the same as your scenario! `class AuthUser; def self.name; "User"; end; end`

Comment: Or similarly, how about: `class AuthUser; def class; User; end; end`

Comment: #class returns the class constant of any Object. Both objects are instances of the same ActiveRecord model: `class User < ApplicationRecord`, and no i do not redefine Class#name.

Comment: It is possible that a class gets reloaded... if I'm in IRB or pry and I do `reload!` the class has a different id, and an object from before reload  still uses the old  Class (with the old class.id)

Comment: Indeed, it has to do with reloading classes. When I set `config.cache_classes` true in the test environment, it works again. I don't know yet, if it's good when Spring is active. Thanks for pointing that out!